How to combine multiple ordered streams efficiently?
Given a List[Stream[F[_], A], where A <: Ordered, and each stream contains an ordered list of elements, what is an effective way to combine these streams into a single, ordered stream of all elements?
So, by example:
  val stream1 = List(1,4,7).toStream
  val stream2 = List(0,2,3,8,9,10).toStream
  val stream3 = List(5,6,11,12).toStream

  val streams = List(stream1, stream2, stream3)
 
  combine(streams).compile.toList // List(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12).

Neither of the streams fit into memory, but the list of streams does, and a few elements of each stream also does. I imagine the solution to be to pull one element from each stream, and push the smallest/greatest of them, while pulling the next element from said stream, until all streams terminate, but I don't know how to express that in code.
Output ordering when elements appear to be equal can be undefined / non-deterministic.

Something like this? https://gist.github.com/johnynek/689199b4ac49364e7c94abef996ae59f

Yes, by the looks of it, exactly like that, thank you!
